# Credit Card Expiry Date validation in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Though this question has been asked previously too, but it didn't work for me. So I am asking this question.
I want to apply validation on expiry date of credit card number. That means if expiry date is before the current date then it should print an error message below the expiry date dropdowns. Below is my HTML code:

```js
$('#billmanagementform').validate({
        rules: {
              cardExpYear: {
                    CCExp: {
                          month: '#cc-exp-month',
                          year: '#cc-exp-year'
                    }
              }
        }
});

$.validator.addMethod('CCExp', function(value, element, params) {
        var minMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
        var minYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var month = parseInt($(params.month).val(), 10);
        var year = parseInt($(params.year).val(), 10);
        return (year > minYear || (year === minYear && month >= minMonth));
  }, 'Your Credit Card Expiration date is invalid.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="billmanagementform">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4">
                        <select name="cc-exp-month" id="cc-exp-month" class="wide100 required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Month</option>
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                            <option value="04">04</option>
                            <option value="05">05</option>
                            <option value="06">06</option>
                            <option value="07">07</option>
                            <option value="08">08</option>
                            <option value="09">09</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="11">11</option>
                            <option value="12">12</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-8">
                        <select name="cc-exp-year" id="cc-exp-year" class="wide100 required">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Year</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            <option value="2021">2021</option>
                            <option value="2022">2022</option>
                            <option value="2023">2023</option>
                            <option value="2024">2024</option>
                            <option value="2025">2025</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
</form>
```

But this code is not at all working for me. Could you please tell that where I am going wrong?

Comment: validate depends on input names not id, remove `#`, and see if it works

Comment: @AdamAzad: it didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validation rules binds an element with validation methods (e.g. `required`, etc.)

> The `rules` object should contain key-value pairs where,  key is the `name`
>   attribute of the element, and  value is an `object` containing one or more
>   validation methods

So, `cardExpYear` must point to `name` attribute of some element(s). Changing the `name` of the `select` should do the trick.

Here's a modified code snippet:

Also, modified the condition inside `CCExp` method to give error only when both month and year have been selected.

```js
$('#billmanagementform').validate({
  rules: {
    cardExpYear: {
      CCExp: {
        month: '#cc-exp-month',
        year: '#cc-exp-year'
      }
    }
  }
});

$.validator.addMethod('CCExp', function(value, element, params) {
  var minMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  var minYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var month = parseInt($(params.month).val(), 10);
  var year = parseInt($(params.year).val(), 10);

  return (!month || !year || year > minYear || (year === minYear && month >= minMonth));
}, 'Your Credit Card Expiration date is invalid.');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="billmanagementform">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4">
    <select name="cardExpYear" id="cc-exp-month" class="wide100 required">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Month</option>
      <option value="01">01</option>
      <option value="02">02</option>
      <option value="03">03</option>
      <option value="04">04</option>
      <option value="05">05</option>
      <option value="06">06</option>
      <option value="07">07</option>
      <option value="08">08</option>
      <option value="09">09</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="11">11</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-8">
    <select name="cardExpYear" id="cc-exp-year" class="wide100 required">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Year</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2020">2020</option>
      <option value="2021">2021</option>
      <option value="2022">2022</option>
      <option value="2023">2023</option>
      <option value="2024">2024</option>
      <option value="2025">2025</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much genius :)

Comment: But there is one problem, if I set current year but past month then only expiration month dropdown is highlighted with red colour , not the expiration year dropdown. Cant I do for both?